# What became of slowing down and recovering the falcon 9 upper stage using large balloons

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, upper-stage, balloons, recovery

On 16 April 2018, Elon Musk posted on twitter

> [This is gonna sound crazy, but …](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/985654333860601856)
>
> [SpaceX will try to bring rocket upper stage back from orbital velocity using a giant party balloon](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/985655249745592320)
>
> [And then land on a bouncy house](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/985684755877265408)

As far as I know this has not happened, and I haven't heard about it at all since those tweets (and their replies).

Did Spacex pursue that idea?

If it was dumped, I assume it had a lot to do with how they wanted to concentrate their efforts on Starship.
Were there any other reasons?

Comment: Ballute - ballistic reentry shield.  They have been testing them for Mars EDL.  F9 is basically as mature as that system is going to  get, Starship is the future.

Comment: The real world happened.